# Firefox headless on Ubuntu18 server throws glxtest process failed (received signal 11)

Tags: ubuntu, testing, firefox, headless

I am trying to use my ubuntu with firefox and geckodriver and selenium to work for testing.
The server is an Ubunutu 18.04 LTS (no desktop !).
Firefox is version 88.0

If I just try a simple test like this (so without selenium etc), just plain in the terminal:

```
firefox --headless http://localhost
```

Then I get errors like this in the terminal:

```
*** You are running in headless mode.
[GFX1-]: No GPUs detected via PCI
[GFX1-]: glxtest: process failed (received signal 11)
```

I have also tried with --disable-gpu but that makes no difference.
Is it actually possible to use firefox headless on a server with no GPU?
Or is there a way to disable this GFX1 test?

Thanks for any help,
gb5256

Comment: I get that exact same pair of GFX warning messages when I launch firefox from a terminal on a perfectly functioning Nvidia laptop where ff launches and runs OK